# How can i retrieve a document using specific field in firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image: FireStore Database]

Hello guys , how can i get all information inside this Document with using the field [ ID ] , i tried to use the where Query but i couldn't success with that

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show the code of what you tried. Without that we're either going to be repeating the docs, or doing your work for you - and neither of those are the goals of Stack Overflow. :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you wanna do this on the firebase website. Let me show you how I did this using my collection.

**Step 1: Go to Filter by field, then select the field you want**

[image: Go to Filter by field, then select the field you want]

**Step 2: Add condition which should be "(==) equal to"**

[image: Add condition which should be "(==) equal to"]

**Step 3: Click on Apply**
[image: Click on Apply]

Voila! Now you can retrieve a document using a specific field in firestore.

Anyhow, if you want to retrieve a document using a specific field inside a frontend code. Then it would be a bit different depending on the language or framework you use.